# pandas fillna with fuzzy search on col names

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe with many col names having _paid as part of the name (eg. A_paid, B_paid. etc). I need to fill miss values in any col that has _paid as part of the name. (note: i am not allowed to replace missing value in other cols with no _paid as part of the name).
I tried to use .fillna(), but not sure how to make it do fuzzy search on col names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select *any* column that has `_paid` in it:

```
paid_cols = df.filter(like="_paid").columns
```

or

```
paid_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("_paid", regex=False)]
```

andthen

```
df[paid_cols] = df[paid_cols].fillna(...)
```

---

If you need `_paid` to be at the end only, then with `$` anchor in a regex:

```
paid_cols = df.filter(regex="_paid$").columns
```

or

```
paid_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("_paid$")]
```

then the same `fillna` above.

Comment: it looks like you have them isolated out then used fillna. then how do i merge them back to replace original cols? @Mustafa Aydın .

Comment: @MeiNanZhu Actually they (should) replace the original columns (tried with sample data).